# Alembic dependency resolution with depends_on

Tags: python, alembic

I'm working on a project with multiple branches, and I'm finding something funny when running my migrations...

I have a `main` branch that has the following revisions: `A --> B --> C`

And then a dev branch with `B' --> C'`

`B'` depends on `B`, and `C'` depends on `C`

`C` has breaking changes that prevent you from running `B'` after it

Now, my expectation was that if I ran `alembic upgrade dev@head` I would get the following order of executions:

`A --> B --> B' --> C --> C'`

With the execution sort of jumping back and forth between the main and the dev branch following a sort of "chronological" order.

However, what I'm getting is

`A --> B --> C --> B' --> C'`

Is there anything I can do to get `A --> B --> B' --> C --> C'`?

Thanks, Fernando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got [an answer](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/discussions/1439) in the Discussions section of the Alembic repo from [zzzeek](https://github.com/zzzeek) himself about this:

> if there's no relationship between C and B' then yes it's expected that these two migrations may occur in any order. So if your migrations have an ordering requirement that C must occur after B', add this relationship using a dependency, that is, the depends_on label. see that documented section for examples, here you'd want to make C dependent on B'.

And, the mentioned docs are [these](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/branches.html#branch-dependencies)